# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'. > java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index

Tags: flutter, macos, dart, gradle

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2:
> > C:\Users\ND\newV\separate\ecfile\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\AssetManifest.json
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 14s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1 Exited (sigterm)